# dev_appserver.py doesn't load appengine_config.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an App Engine app running locally using `dev_appserver.py`. In the app directory I have the standard `appengine_config.py` that is supposed to execute on every request made to the app. In the past it used to execute the module, but suddenly it stopped doing it.

In another app runs on the same machine it works fine.

I checked with Process Monitor to see if the file is loaded from another location, but it's not (I can see the other app's file being loaded).

Any ideas why `appengine_config.py` is not executed?

Comment: appengine_config.py only runs when an new instance is started. There is no reason to run it for every request. By the way: appengine_config.py is great for changing config defauls (module settings) using lib_config. More info here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Comment: @voscausa In production you are right, `appengine_config.py` is loaded when an instance is created. But on the dev server it is loaded every request so you don't have to stop and start the server every time you change the file.

Comment: YES, there is a reason: debugging.

Comment: @voscausa I know it's for debugging, that's why I expected the execution of this file in the first place.

Comment: @Tzach were you able to solve this me too facing same issue ? If yes please let me know the solution which made this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem before. Solved by changing the loading method in `app.yaml` to wsgi, for example, from:

> script: my_app/main.py

To:

> script: my_app.main.application

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Nope !! Didn't help in my case